# $f$ is measurable. Prove that $f$ has to be constant on $(0,∞)$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f : (0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be measurable and $0 < \lambda < 1$. Suppose that

$$f(x + y) = \lambda f(x) + (1 − \lambda)f(y)$$

holds for any $x, y > 0$. Prove that $f$ has to be constant on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Please add some more information on what you have tried, or list some of the techniques you have been taught about to solve this kind of problem, so we know what level of knowledge to phrase the answers at

Answer (score 2):

**Lemma.** For $n\in\mathbb N$ and $x\in\mathbb R$, we have  $f(nx)=f(x)$. In particular, $f(n)=f(1)$.

*Proof by induction on $n$.* For $n=1$ it is clear. If the statement is true for some $n\in\mathbb N$, then $$f((n+1)\cdot x)=\lambda \underbrace{f(nx)}_{=f(x)}+(1-\lambda)f(x)=f(x). \square$$

Hence, we have by the Lemma for all $x\in\mathbb R$ and $n\in\mathbb N$: 
\begin{gather}\tag 1\label 1 f(x+n)=\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(1)=f(x+2n)\\ f(x+2n)=\lambda f(x+n)+(1-\lambda) f(1)\tag 2 \label 2\end{gather}

and thus by dividing by $\lambda\neq 0$, $$f(x)=f(x+n).$$ From the Lemma and the condition on $f$ we have $$f(x+n)=\lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda) f(1).$$

Thus $$(1-\lambda) f(x)=(1-\lambda) f(1)$$ from which we get (since $\lambda\neq1$) that $f(x)=f(1)$ for all $x$ i.e. that $f$ is constant.

**Note that the measurability of $f$ was not needed.**

Answer (score 0):

Measurability is actually not needed here for the conclusion to hold. Note that the hypothesis implies $f(2x)=f(x)$ and then by an easy induction $f(kx)=f(x)$ for $k>0$ integer.

Let $g(x)=f(x)-f(1)$, then:

$g(x+y)-(\lambda g(x)+(1-\lambda)g(y))=f(x+y)-f(1)-(\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y))+f(1)=0$, so $g$ satisfies same relation but $g(1)=0$. Then $g(k)=0$ for $k>0$ integer and since $g(kx)=g(x)$, we get $g(\frac{p}{q})=g(q\frac{p}{q})=0$ for any $r=\frac{p}{q}>0$ rational, so $g(x+r)=\lambda g(x)$ for any $x>0, r>0$, $r$ rational.

Since then $g(x+2r)=\lambda g(x)$ as $2r$ is rational too, but also $g(x+2r)=\lambda g(x+r)=\lambda^2 g(x)$, we get that $\lambda g(x)=\lambda^2 g(x)$, hence $g(x)=0$ for arbitrary positive $x$, hence $f(x)=f(1)$. Done!

Comment: Nice answer, I had a very similar idea. As a remark, one can assume without loss of generality that $\lambda=\frac12$ since $$2f(x+y)=f(x+y)+f(y+x)=f(x)+f(y)$$
However, this doesn’t seem to improve your already nice proof

Comment: @Maximilian that's a good observation! I originally thought that you need local boundness ae (which is where measurability is used in showing that an additive measurable function is linear as opposed to the wild non-measurable counterxamples that use bases of R/Q) but it wasn;t needed...

Comment: why $g(x+y) - \lambda g(x) - (1-\lambda) g(y) = f(x+y) - f(1)$? Shouldn't it just be equal to zero?

Comment: @lye it is zero in the answer but may not show immediately on small screens